# Type parameter 'T' has a circular constraint

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic type which will consist of the argument type, and an array of itself under `nodes`. My code:

```
type Foo<T> = T & {
    nodes: Foo<T>[]
}

function Bar<A extends Foo<A>>():null{
    return null;
}
```

When trying to run it, I'm getting

> Type parameter 'A' has a circular constraint

Which I understand. The problem is, this is exactly what I want. I want to use it like so:

```
interface Vegetables{
    id:number
    nodes: Vegetables[]
}

interface Fruits{
    id:number
    nodes: Fruits
}

Bar<Vegetables>()
Bar<Fruits>
```

And I'm not sure what I'm missing

[code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxWVAZFAbwFgAoKcqAOzgBMIBnALlgRVQG0BdUgX1NIBmAV0oBjYAEs4lKACEAhgCdEAQSgQAHsAiUa9FkhWpUACgCUjSkIA214mQqKIwIYplXbAbl78SAej8oOnoJJxooIXp5AHMIRl8JSm1FAXlRaAA1CFjgeQAjawZ7CigJGkshAFs8iEVSEupg5iyc-ML6Lh8SUkTk1PTYRSEJYHpiijKK6tr6ikaGZhghkfou0gVlFuc2hlMzdaVEJeHR1CA)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a workaround.

Since we're extending, we're keeping the `T`. So this should still work

```
type Foo<T> = {
    nodes: Foo<T>[]
}

function Bar<A extends Foo<A>>():null{
    return null;
}

// desired usage:

interface Vegetables{
    id:number
    nodes: Vegetables[]
}

interface Fruits{
    id:number
    nodes: Fruits[]
}

Bar<Vegetables>()
Bar<Fruits>
```

But if anyone has a way to make it work in the original way, please leave a response

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what this type parameter is supposed to do, but I have the feeling you want this to fail

```js
interface Stuff {
    id:number
    nodes: Vegetables[]
    type: 'stuff' // adding a discriminant so that Stuff ≠ Vegetables
}

// @ts-expect-error: Stuff is not Stuff & { nodes: Stuff[] }
Bar<Stuff>()
```

It is not pretty, but you can do it this way

```js
function Bar<
    A extends Foo<unknown> & Check,
    Check = A extends Foo<A> ? unknown: never
>():null{
    return null;
}
```

Since `unknown` is the neutral element of intersection, `Check` does not affect the first type parameter when the constraint is met, and since this condition does not return A, it is not a circular constraint.

Now, you don't need to return `never` when the constraint is not met, any type which is incompatible with `Foo<unknown>` will be an error, so you can return some error message explaining that `A` should be recursive.